# Is it possible to add WHERE clauses when retrieving relationships?

Tags: doctrine, limit, where-clause, relationships

In doctrine, is it possible to add a WHERE clause when fetching a property of an object that corresponds to a relationship?

In terms of concept, let's say I want to retrieve only the first 3 blog posts made in the last 5 days.  My "blog" object has a "posts" property which is defined as a relationship.

Update...

As some people are having some difficulties understanding what I mean by a relationship:

```
class Blog extends Doctrine_Record {

       ...

       public function setUp() {

            $this->hasMany("Note as Posts", array(
                "local" => "blog_name",
                "foreign" => "post_id",
                "refClass" => "BlogPost"
            ));

       }
}
```

As you can see, this is an explicit relationship as supported by doctrine.  When I query using it:

```
     $instanceOfBlog->Posts...........
```

I'd like to know if I can add additional clauses at that time.

Comment: Why don't you add the where clause before executing the query?

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: I'm not sure if example code is needed given the explanation I provided.  Problem being, I don't know the code to give an example of!
I have a relationship on a class.  I want to add WHERE clauses when accessing the relationship.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I follow you, but if it's what I think then in your `BlogTable` class:

```
public function getRecentPosts()
{
  $qry = self::createQuery("b")
    ->innerJoin("b.Posts p")
    ->where("p.created_at > ?", date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-5 days")))
    ->orderBy("p.created_at DESC")
    ->limit(3);

  $results = $qry->execute();
}
```

Is that what you were after? This is based on the `created_at` field in the Posts object, and assumes a relationship is defined between the `Blog` and `Posts` tables.

I may have misunderstood your question entirely however :-)